# Why default/suggested practice in Grails CRUD so initialize with prams on Create

Tags: grails

Creating a new controller in Grails, by default generates create method like so:

```
def create() {
    respond new Book(params), model: [......]
}
```

I would like to know what is the reasoning behind it, why not simply new Book() or nothing at all?

Furthermore, using the same method with a Command Object would give an error, ex:

`No such property: action for class: com.BookCommand`

I get that params includes action property and Command Object does not but neither does the domain Domain class.

Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data binder used in controllers is slightly relaxed about properties that don't exist in the class, primarily because of "extra" parameters like the action and controller names. Only persistent and bindable properties are set (and `id`, `version`, `class`, and `metaClass` are always ignored).

The reason that the `Book` is created from `params` and not just a new default instance is to allow setting some initial default values, e.g.

```
/book/create?foo=42&bar=purple
```

which would set the initial value of the `foo` and `bar' properties in the GSP form.

Comment: Thanks, Burt. Makes perfect sense.